# Is there a built-in MariaDB method to export index creation statements in SQL form?

Tags: mariadb, ddl, database-indexes

I would like to temporarily disable index updates. This seems not to be possible, so instead I would like to just drop and recreate the indexes after I'm done changing the data. I have found the `SHOW indexes FROM $table` command, but that only generates some some human-readable ascii art. Next, I tried `mysqldump --no-data` (and some other options), but this puts the `key` statements inside the `create table` and does not have separate statements for adding indexes.

Is there a way to simply export `CREATE INDEX ...` statements from an existing database/table? Essentially an equivalent to sqlite's `.dump`, which includes such statements.

Comment: *Is there a way to simply export CREATE INDEX ... statements from an existing database/table?* Create database backup with structure-only command line option (--no-data) then remove all statements except indices creation ones from the dump.

Comment: @Akina The problem with that is that there are no separate index creation statements. It's like `CREATE TABLE users (id int key, score int key, name varchar)` instead of `CREATE TABLE users (id int, score int, name varchar); CREATE INDEX users_score ON users (score);`.

Comment: If so then the only visible way is to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA and recreate the indices definitions. And FOREIGN KEYs definitions too...

Answer (score 0):

What about `ALTER TABLE $table DISABLE KEYS`? This disables the index updates.

Comment: Only non-unique indices are disabled. And not all engines supports this table option (afair InnoDB does not support).

Comment: Somehow I did not find this syntax before, that would have been perfect! But unfortunately, as Akina mentions, I am using InnoDB and [this is not supported](https://serverfault.com/questions/234893/how-to-disable-keys-in-mysql-innodb-tables). Maybe I should switch to Aria, though. Checking that out now, thanks for the tip!